# Какой View использовать, чтобы сделать выдвигающийся текст с доп информацией?

Tags: android

Какой View и как использовать, чтобы получить это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы текст с доп информацией раздвигался и задвигался

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать анимацию. Пример анимации можно посмотреть здесь: https://annimon.com/article/468

Comment: [Выбирайте](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=expandable) что вам больше подойдёт.